# code to sort csv. Using full date (yyyy-mm-dd) to label with different visits (PACE01, PACE02 etc)

Tags: r, csv, sorting, date

I have a csv. I want to load it into R to get the desired outcome (highlighted). For example study id 256 was taken on differing dates (ie. different vists) I want PACE01, PACE02, PACE03 or PACE04 to be added for each recurring visit respectively.

Some years have two visits so I cant just use year. I need to take into account whole date.

Hope this makes sense, I would really appreciate your help. I have 14,000+ samples to sort.

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c35J4.png)

Comment: Even a quick, scant browse on SO shld make it clear pictures are not data or code unless one has image processing questions. There is no code. There is no data. i.e. there is no reproducible example. We don't even know if you know R. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: Hi I know some R coding. I have read the csv file into R. This CSV file has all rows except for the desired outcome row (this is what I need help with). I would really appreciate your input.                                                        MyData <- read.csv(file="Desired_Outcome.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

Comment: I also now I can use [,2] or [2,] to access certain columns and rows.

Comment: If you could even specify how to determine to determine the sequence number that is added after PACE, that would help tremendously: I don't see how to get it from the data in the image that you provide.

Comment: the sequence number after PACE is the visit number. i.e study.ID 256 has multiple visit at different dates. The earliest date would be PACE01 and the latest (most recent) would be PACE04. Just using year wouldn't be feasible as visit 2 and visit 3 both occur in 2010. Hope this makes sense @PaulLemmens

Comment: So you first need to group by ID, determine the unique visit dates, sort them, add a sequence number, and integrate that info back into your original data frame (merge(), after exercise, is your friend).

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Is there anyway you could help me in how to go about doing this @PaulLemmens

Comment: @PaulLemmens could I ask for further clarification?

Comment: @JBrowne13 yes you can by all means, but if you want a coded solution, I need data that I can readily import in R.